# "ON DELETE CASCADE" does not work when using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

Here I provide a completely reproducible code, which demonstrates the whole issue. And the issue is that, when I delete rows from the "parent" table, corresponding rows from the "child" table are not deleted, even though they have a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` specified. So this is the code:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> cnx = sqlite3.connect("mytest.db")
>>> cursor = cnx.cursor()
>>> cnx.execute("BEGIN")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f0ab0923490>
>>> cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test_table (id integer)")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f0ab0923420>
>>> cursor.execute("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_primary ON test_table(id)")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f0ab0923420>
>>> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (id) VALUES (1),(2),(3)")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f0ab0923420>
>>> cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test_table_2(id_fk integer, txt text,  FOREIGN KEY (id_fk) REFERENCES test_table(id) ON DELETE CASCADE)")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f0ab0923420>
>>> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_table_2 (id_fk, txt) VALUES (1,\"one\"),(2,\"two\"),(3,\"three\")")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f0ab0923420>
>>> res = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table_2")
>>> res
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f0ab0923420>
>>> for r in res:
...     print(r)
...
(1, 'one')
(2, 'two')
(3, 'three')
>>> cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f0ab0923420>
>>> cursor.execute("DELETE FROM test_table WHERE id = 1")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f0ab0923420>
>>> res = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table_2")
>>> for r in res:
...     print(r)
...
(1, 'one')
(2, 'two')
(3, 'three')
```

As you can see, I even explicitly run `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` before I do `DELETE`, but it does not help. BTW, if I run these commands in `sqlite3>` prompt, then everything is ok. So, the whole problem is with `Python` library.

Comment: If there's a problem in Python, you should raise it as a bug.

Comment: I guess, the problem is not with Python itself, but with the library. Or, probably, I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `sqlite3` is in the standard library, so you can still report on https://bugs.python.org

Comment: Does it work if you do it from outside Python? I don't see how the library could influence this, it should just be passing everything to sqlite.

Comment: I've already said it in my question, that it works outside Python in pure sqlite3 prompt

Comment: BTW. I even tested my code with `cnx.isolation_level = None`, to make my code fully transactional. I did that just before `cursor = cnx.cursor()`. But it did not help at all.

Comment: BUT. If I do `cnx.isolation_level = None` just before `cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")`, then it starts working. But I cannot understand why and I cannot understand logic behind that. In fact if it is the only way to make cascading deletes work, that you have to wrap these deletes in a single transaction, then it is a big problem, but more than that, it's unreasonable to differentiate "simple" and "cascading" deletes.

Comment: I started an issue at Python bug tracker - http://bugs.python.org/issue26043 But I'm not even sure, whether it is a real bug or not.

Comment: @Jacobian Are you saying you need to sometimes do cascading deletes and sometimes not? That's a design smell; the entire point of foreign keys is that the data pointed to by the foreign key is always valid. By forcing a delete to go through by disabling FKs, you're violating their invariants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`FOREIGN_KEYS`](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) pragma is a no-op inside of a transaction.

> This pragma is a no-op within a transaction; foreign key constraint enforcement may only be enabled or disabled when there is no pending BEGIN or SAVEPOINT.

Comment: I do not totally understand this point. If it is so, what should I do to make it work, or to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: @Jacobian Execute `PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = on` outside of a transaction. Don't execute it after you execute a `BEGIN` statement or after Python implicitly starts a transaction via an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a minute.